# Delphi FMX MapView - custom map overlay

Tags: android, ios, delphi, android-mapview

Does anyone know how to make custom (bit)map image over Google maps in Delphi TMapview component? Something like this: [Custom Disney Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gfwz.jpg)

I want to make Android, iOS application with custom map overlay...

Zdravko

Comment: Can you not just create a TImage child for the TMapView component?

Comment: I think, there must be a better way... This is from google API, but I don't know how to do it in Delphi... [Google maps overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)